# How to enforce unique key across tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am using PostgreSQL 12 and PostGIS.

### The Behaviour I want

I have a table `LOCATIONS` which contains geographic data and a `ROWID` as Primary Key. I also have a table `VALUES` which contains arbitrary values. I want to map each entry in `VALUES` to either no or a single location. I can easily do this with a foreign key in `VALUES` referencing `LOCATIONS.ROWID`.

### The problem

The issue I have is that my location data is spread across multiple tables (which I can't change). Is there a way to **add a field to `VALUES` that references exactly one row under one of the location tables?**

I think this would require a unique identifier across multiple location tables. However, I do not know how to achieve this, while not relying on the correctness of inserted data.

### Table Format for clarification

#### `VALUES`

| rowid | value | geoID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 42 | 0 |
| 1 | 69 | 1 |

#### `LOCATIONS A`

| rowid | name | geoID | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USA | 0 | POLYGON(...) |
| 1 | UK | 2 | POLYGON(...) |

#### `LOCATIONS B`

| rowid | name | geoID | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NYC | 1 | POLYGON(...) |
| 1 | LA | 3 | POLYGON(...) |

Comment: What about merging the two (or more?) location tables into a single one and create views that simulate the old multi-table design (which sounds wrong to begin with based on the information given). That way any application that uses `locations_a` simply accesses the view. Once you have a single table, you can easily create a foreign key constraint

Comment: I think this is not possible as the PostGIS Object (the thing in the geometry field) can only have a fixed type (like polygon, point, rectangle etc.) per table. And I need to use PostGIS to perform geography calculations and comparisons. So I cant have point based locations (e.g. location of a store) and polygon based locations (e.g. area of a country) in the same table. 

If it were not for the location stuff, I would never even think about splitting this up in multiple tables.

Comment: Is it possible for one location to be referenced by more than one value?

Comment: @clamp Yes. The idea behind that system is, that the database base provides fixed locations (like countries, states, cities) and the user can map various values to some locations. It would also be nice if a user could define his own locations and map to those, but that is of secondary concern.

Comment: You could use a link table with foreign key into values and foreign keys into each of the location tables then (in that link table) add a Unique on the id_values and a check constraint or trigger to ensure that only one location_id is set.